# Replace any uicontrol with same Auto Layout constraints

Tags: uibutton, uitextfield, ios-autolayout

I want to replace a UITextField with UIButton. But i want that the UIButton will contain the same constraints which UITextField have. Can i replace any control like this Or I have to delete the UITextField and put a UIButton and set the constraints again.

Answer (score 0):

Its always better and a good practice to replace the control and add the required constraints. The other way of doing is to put a UIButton on top of UILabel and assign left, top, width and height constants same as UILabel (Certainly i wont prefer this way but if you feel lazy to delete and add all the required constraints the you can go by the second approach). Hope this helps :)